# Retrieve Object From Spinner Array And Set It

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, spinner

I'm trying retrieve an object from my spinner array and set it to a certain constant, in this case "EFFECT_AQUA"

My array

```
String[] spinnerValues = {"Aqua", "Mono", "Blackbird", "Negative"};
```

when the user clicks on the "Aqua" in the spinner I want the screen to change to Aqua.

My spinner is set and called

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_show);
mySpinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.custom_spinner,spinnerValues));
```

But not sure how should I approach. Seen many different answers but haven't found anything working.

I know my switch will come in this part

```
class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    }
}
```

Any help is appricated!!

Comment: do you want to change background of your screen as per selection?

Comment: Yes, per spinner item. For example when you click on spinner and the different array items appear, each item should have its own background

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve an object from your spinner array on item click, you can easily do it with the position parameter in the method `onItemSelected`.

For example :-

```
class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   String itemSelected = spinnerValues[position];
   //Set this to a constant
}
```

}

Now if you select **Aqua**, then code will set the variable itemSelected to **Aqua**.

I hope this is what you need

Comment: I will also give this a try and see if this solution meets my needs as well!

Answer (score 0):

```
final Spinner cardStatusSpinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.text_interested);
String cardStatusString;
cardStatusSpinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
        cardStatusString = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  }
```

put the code below to get the item first then you can manipulate by taking the values like aqua or any color.

```
 spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,spinnerValues));
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)view;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tv.getText().toString(), 5000).show();
        switch(tv.getText().toString()){
        case "Aqua":{
            //change  the color to aqua
            break;
        }
        case " ...":{
            //
            break;
        }
        //.... for all the option
        }
    }
```

Comment: Or You can get the string directly from string contant. for that you have to use the line like  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
       String color = spinnerValues[position];
        switch(color){

Comment: Thanks! This solutions works perfectly and should be upvoted. I'm using the public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { String color = spinnerValues[position]; switch(color) implementation. One last question. To stop showing the effect I'm using  mCamera.stopPreview();
                        mCamera.startPreview(); to stop the effect being display and then starting the preview again. Is this the recommended approach?